# Excel: Count rows in a column to the last active cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code below that works perfectly but whenever I come across on an empty cell it the counting stops there and overwrite everything below.

So for example at there are strings row1, row2, row3(empty cell) ,row4(have strings). The macro will stop at row 2 then will type the results at row4 and beyond and will over write everything. I've seen some codes online but does not fit on my code. Thanks for the help.

```
Public Sub Test()

Dim row_number As Long
Dim count_of_Dog As Long
Dim count_of_Cat As Long
Dim count_of_others As Long
Dim count_of_all As Long
Dim items As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row

count_of_Dog = 0
count_of_Cat = 0
count_of_others = 0
count_of_all = 0

For i = 1 To LastRow
    items = ws.Range("N" & i)
    If InStr(items, "dog") > 0 Then
        count_of_Dog = count_of_Dog + 1
    ElseIf InStr(items, "cat") > 0 Then
        count_of_Cat = count_of_Cat + 1
    ElseIf items <> "" Then
        count_of_others = count_of_others + 1

    End If
Next i

count_of_all = count_of_Dog + count_of_Cat + count_of_others

Range("N" & LastRow).Offset(3, 0).Value = "Count"
Range("N" & LastRow).Offset(4, 0).Value = count_of_Dog
Range("N" & LastRow).Offset(5, 0).Value = count_of_Cat
Range("N" & LastRow).Offset(6, 0).Value = count_of_others
Range("N" & LastRow).Offset(7, 0).Value = count_of_all
Range("N" & LastRow).Offset(3, 1).Value = "Keywords"
Range("N" & LastRow).Offset(4, 1).Value = "DOGS"
Range("N" & LastRow).Offset(5, 1).Value = "CATS"
Range("N" & LastRow).Offset(6, 1).Value = "Others"
Range("N" & LastRow).Offset(7, 1).Value = "Total"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following, I've replaced the Do Loop with a For Loop, and found the LastRow with data in column N then used the same Offset as you did to write the total values, I've also removed any Select or Activate methods as these slow the code down:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()
Dim count_of_Dog As Long
Dim count_of_Cat As Long
Dim count_of_others As Long
Dim count_of_all As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row

count_of_Dog = 0
count_of_Cat = 0
count_of_others = 0
count_of_all = 0

For i = 1 To LastRow
    If InStr(ws.Range("N" & i).Value, "dog") > 0 Then
        count_of_Dog = count_of_Dog + 1
    ElseIf InStr(ws.Range("N" & i).Value, "cat") > 0 Then
        count_of_Cat = count_of_Cat + 1
    ElseIf ws.Range("N" & i).Value <> "" Then
        count_of_others = count_of_others + 1
    End If
Next i

count_of_all = count_of_Dog + count_of_Cat + count_of_others

Range("N" & LastRow).Offset(3, 0).Value = "Count"
Range("N" & LastRow).Offset(4, 0).Value = count_of_Dog
Range("N" & LastRow).Offset(5, 0).Value = count_of_Cat
Range("N" & LastRow).Offset(6, 0).Value = count_of_others
Range("N" & LastRow).Offset(7, 0).Value = count_of_all
Range("N" & LastRow).Offset(3, 1).Value = "Keywords"
Range("N" & LastRow).Offset(4, 1).Value = "DOGS"
Range("N" & LastRow).Offset(5, 1).Value = "CATS"
Range("N" & LastRow).Offset(6, 1).Value = "Others"
Range("N" & LastRow).Offset(7, 1).Value = "Total"
End Sub
```

Comment: I ran it and gave it a Run-time error '13': Type mismatch.  When I degged it, it's point to the line `If InStr(items, "dog") Then`

Comment: I don't get any error when testing, please make sure all your variables are declared appropriately...

Comment: Strange, i copied your code and pasted it. Tried multiple times but still getting the error.

Comment: Made a couple of modifications, please try it now, I'm not getting any issues, and its working as expected.

Comment: Suggest to overwrite the five summary lines before counting, otherwise you increment the `count_of_others` variable by 5 at every code execution and extend the checked range to the bottom including the summary :-)

Comment: it's now giving me error variable not defined and highlighting the `For i`

Comment: @Jonathan I've updated my answer, simply declare it as `Dim i as Long`, that should do it,... I think :)

Answer (score 0):

To find the really last row, you must scroll to the bottom of the sheet and then jump up. To do it programmatically:

```
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
End With
```

But this is not the best approach, I think. Better would be at first to define your range and then to look for those dogs and cats. Substitute your Do...Until loop with object loop:

```
Dim rngToSearch As Range
Dim cl As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        rngToSearch = Range(.Range("N1"), .Range("N" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))


        For Each cl In rngToSearch
            If InStr(cl.Value, "dog") Then
                count_of_dog = count_of_dog + 1
            ElseIf InStr(cl.Value, "cat") Then
                count_of_cat = count_of_cat + 1
            ElseIf cl.Value <> "" Then count_of_others 1
        End If

    End With
```

I have also re-written your code for summary. Put it between the End If and End With, if you wish:

```
    With .Range("N" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
        Range(.Offset(5, 0), .Offset(8, 0)).Value = Array( _
            "Count", "Keywords", "DOGS", "CATS", "Others", "Total")
        Range(.Offset(4, 1), .Offset(8, 1)).Values = Array( _
            count_of_Dog, count_of_Cat, count_of_others, count_of_all)
    End With
```

This should put your summary just three lines below your data.

Comment: Tried it and it gave me a Compile error: Expected Sub, Function, or property.

Comment: typo in: For Each cl in rngToSearch

Answer (score 0):

You are using correct method if the column is fixed i.e.

`LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row`

However, I am surprised to know that it is not fetching the real last blank row. The only situation where I can imagine this happening is you have some data on the last few rows of the spreadsheet.

What value is returned by following code?

`MsgBox ws.Range("N1").EntireColumn.Find("*", ws.Range("N1"), , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row`

Comment: it's returning the correct value of the rows but for some weird reason it's not doing what i want it to do.